# DisconnectedContext error when running Unit Tests in debug in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, visual-studio-2015

I have this problem with running unit tests in VS2015 Enterprise. Whenever I run any unit test in debug mode, I get the following error:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' has detected a problem in 'my_path_to_VS\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\te.processhost.managed.exe'.

I tried running repair on VS2015 and it did not help. Tried uninstalling and installling again and the issue persist. The strange thing that I have a code on SVN and my friend in able to run the same code in debug on his machine without any issues.

Just running the test (without debugger) works without any problems.

I do have a ReSharper installed. Could that be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**
Ok so Resharper is causing this issue. This issue only happens when I am running the test through the ReSharper icon (next to the TestMethod name). When I do Test->Debug->All Tests it runs fine. Any ideas? Maybe ReSharper bug?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I also have Rashaper and faced with this problem, no matter from where I am calling the tests (VS or Resharper). I've overcome this by changing the target architecture of the tests and the projects to the x64. But the source of the problem is still unknown for me.
[image: Settings]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however this did not solve the problem for me :(. Maybe it can help other though.

Comment: this fixed it for me.Ty !

Comment: Fixed for me.  Found on 2015 x64 machine, test settings were set to x86.

Comment: This also happens if you are running test debug when the solution has been set to Release instead of Debug :-)

Comment: Did not work for me directly. As @BoMortensen pointed, I have been toggling between release and debug modes. Re opened the solution and did a clean & rebuild. Solved!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exception while debugging a WCF service in Visual Studio 2015. No usage of ReSharper. Changing the default architecture as suggested by shfire to X64 fixed it for me.

Because my project is a migrated Visual Studio 2012 project I compared the default processor architecture with the settings in VS2012. In VS2012 the default architecture isn't selected or selectable! I think this is a new bug and/or feature of VS2015 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you set the compiler to "Release" instead of "Debug". That solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue here. Fixed-it I don't know how :
Set the target system as x64 from Any CPU.
Run "debug all tests" => no tests where found. (?)
Tryed to manualy run debug on my empty first test, apparently no action.
Got back from x64 to Any CPU.

Now it works ... Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11213271)

Comment: @jogo: This seems to me as possible workaround..., its neither critique nor request for clarification. Did you read it?

Answer (score 0):

This exception also occurs if you have installed CodeRush for Roslyn Preview extension in VS2015. This extension have some functionality for unit testing, so it appears that this is common for all extensions which extend to unit testing in Visual Studio. Can be solved by uninstalling (not disabling) this extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, my unit tests used external application run in new process. I run visual studio in administrator mode and it resolved problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting this problem doing ordinary debugging (using Visual Studio 2015, of a Windows Forms application, which was a first project first created using earlier versions of Visual Studio). It happens occasionally.

I think it may be related to `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` in the project's Debug properties page, i.e. I hope that disabling that option will prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error while using the following:

```vb
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
  Sub()
    Do
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub()
           TimeTextBox.Text = Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")                                               
                       End Sub)
        ' thread not a problem
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1500)
        ' Task delay fail with disconnection
        'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1500)
    Loop While isrunning
  End Sub)
```